# Plotting based on time-values pairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

First off, I'm just getting started with R and ggplot. However, I do have a specific problem I'd like to solve using R:

I have a table with experimental data like this:

| Measurements | 0.25s | 0.5s | 0.75s | 1.0s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| measurement_1 | 0.974 | 0.944 | 0.928 | 0.911 |
| measurement_2 | 0.945 | 0.932 | 0.811 | 0.800 |
| etc. |  |  |  |  |

So there are several measurements, each done at specific time intervals (0,974 at 0.25s, 0.944 at 0.5s). I'm not sure this is ideally formatted.

Now to start off I want a x,y-Plot with the time-intervals as the x-Axis and the measurements as values. So at x=0.25s one dot at 0.974 and another dot (maybe in another color) at 0.945.

However I struggle with this simple task, I think my dataframe needs to be formatted differently, yet I don't know what's the best way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; the data needs to be formatted differently. First, you need to re arrange your data from *wide format* to *long format*. For more details, I recommend looking at [chapter 12 of R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Your example worked using the `tidyverse`:

```
# import packages
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# your original data (wide format)
df_wide <- data.frame(Measurements = c("measurement_1", "measurement_2"),
                      "0.25s" = c(0.974, 0.945), 
                      "0.5s" = c(0.944, 0.932),
                      "0.75s" = c(0.928, 0.811),
                      "1s" = c(0.911, 0.800))

# use function pivot_longer() to convert to long format
df_long <- pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = !"Measurements", 
                        names_to = "time_interval", 
                        values_to = "values")

# plot your long format data using ggplot()
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time_interval, y = values, color = Measurements)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is that your data is in a wide format instead of a long format. If you reshape it, it is easier to plot with ggplot2.

First we'll make some dummy data with the same shape as you showed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- matrix(runif(16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4,
               dimnames = list(paste0("measurement_", 1:4),
                               c("0.25s", "0.5s", "0.75s", "1.0s")))

print(data)
#>                   0.25s      0.5s     0.75s      1.0s
#> measurement_1 0.8934145 0.9467071 0.3683058 0.3742559
#> measurement_2 0.4608504 0.2216749 0.8835656 0.8980183
#> measurement_3 0.9700504 0.0320177 0.7907006 0.8851707
#> measurement_4 0.9027836 0.6589359 0.1600577 0.6270612
```

Here is how to reshape and plot it:

```
# Reshape the data to long format
df <- reshape2::melt(data)
colnames(df) <- c("measurement", "time", "value")

# Convert time from character to numeric
df$seconds <- as.numeric(gsub("s$", "", df$time))

ggplot(df, aes(seconds, value, colour = measurement)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>